# multipath default grouping policy not observed?

Tags: multipath-storage

RHEL 6.4, Yes I know it's old. I have no choice.

According to the multipath.conf man page, the default grouping policy is *multibus*. That is, multipaths should be shown as follows:

```
# multipath -ll
mpathc (360002ac0000000000000086c00002ce2) dm-0 3PARdata,VV size=16G features='0' hwhandler='0' wp=rw
`-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=1 status=active
  |- 2:0:0:0 sdd 8:48  active ready running
  |- 3:0:0:0 sde 8:64  active ready running
  |- 3:0:1:0 sdf 8:80  active ready running
  `- 2:0:1:0 sdg 8:96  active ready running
```

There is a single group with four paths in it. Multibus. So far so good.

Now, when connecting to an iSCSI target, I get a *failover* configuration. I swear the multipath.conf file contains nothing about the grouping policy, so that I expect a default *multibus* grouping:

```
# multipath -v2
create: rusty13lun1 (1201311201301) undef L-and-D,Spinning Rust size=16G features='0' hwhandler='0' wp=undef
|-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=1 status=undef
| `- 4:0:0:1 sdh 8:112 undef ready running
`-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=1 status=undef
  `- 5:0:0:1 sdl 8:176 undef ready running
```

There is one group per path. Failover.

When explicitly requesting *multibus* for the iSCSI LUN, a multibus configuration is created as expected.

I double checked this with *dmsetup* (sorry, I didn't save the output).

My questions:
**Is multibus really the default?
What might make dmsetup or multipathing choose a certain policy?**

This is on a training system that I currently don't have access to, so that I can't investigate any further unfortunately.

Comment: Try: `multipath -p multibus
multipath -r​`